# w3schools countdown timer: why does my index.html file open to a blank page instead of the timer?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
        p {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 60px;
          margin-top: 0px;
        }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
    
      <p id="timer"></p>
    
      <script>
      // Set the date we're counting to
      var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 19, 2020 13:00:00").getTime();

      // Update the countdown every second
      var updateEverySecond = setInterval(function() {

        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the remaining time between now and the count down date
        var remaining = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes, and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(remaining / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var mins = Math.floor((remaining % 1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var sec = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
// Output the result in an element with id="timer"
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
        + mins + "m " + sec + "s ";
        // If the countdown is over, display a message
        if (remaining < 0) {
          clearInterval(updateEverySecond);
     document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
      }, 1000);

      </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The above is the contents of my index.html file.
Here's a link to the w3schools page I'm following:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp
I've tried creating a server.js file in the project directory, and I can include the contents of that file, or any other files if that would clarify my question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Here's a hint, looks at the line `var mins = Math.floor((remaining % 1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));`

Comment: On the line : var mins = Math.floor((remaining % 1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); you have one too many ")". Remove the last ")" char and it should start working.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, will try this ASAP!

Comment: It's working now, as advised, the problem was that extra closing parenthesis, thank's so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Line

```
var mins = Math.floor((remaining % 1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
```

to this

```
var mins = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
```

and it will work

Answer (score -2):

If you copy the whole code strait from the website, and paste it into your HTML document , It SHOULD WORK. IF THAT DOESN'T WORK, then don't name your file "index.html" sometimes files may override